# Apache/php appending extra info to pages? Breaking website

Tags: php, jquery, apache

I have a website that I've had running on various linux distros so far (debian/redhat mostly)
I've currently set up another machine on a RHEL5 and am having a few issues. My best guess is that it is related to the httpd configuration but I haven't been able to track it down.

Here are the tests I've done to figure the issue out:

-running a simple Jquery .get() command and analysing the resulting data:

```
.get('testing.php',function(data){
if(data != ''){
  alert('not empty');
 }
});
```

with testing.php as follows:

```
<?php die(); ?>
```

This would generally never send anything out. It doesn't on my other installs (including another RHEL install) but this time around it is sending the "not empty" alert.

Another example would be:

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $PngImageBlob;
?>
```

With $PnGImageBlob a valid png image blob. The image comes out broken (no errors show though, I get what looks like a valid imageblob if I remove the header)

From both of these I've been wondering if there might not be an issue with apache appending some form of information to the page and thus breaking my data. Or maybe it's a trailing space issue in which case my application is a little too big for me to possibly track them down. Is there some sort of httpd / php configuration option that could help me out here?

I'm currently running php 5.3.6 , Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)

Comment: try to use ajax() instead of get() and specify what type of return are you expecting. also try to monitor the XHR request to see what is the actual response. I suppose the request is made on the same domain.

Comment: the .get is just an example and not really the issue here. I could easily work my way around it by rendering json data with my php file (and that works). The real issue is that it's site wide and currently breaking all my dynamic images (and probably some other jquery functionality.) It's a pretty big project and I don't think it would be currently possible for me to test and debug everything. Especially considering it's worked fine up until this last install

Comment: check not to have any other output before the echo $Png...

Comment: Thanks for your time Elzo. Unfortunately there is no other output. Like I've said before, my site works perfectly with other setups. When I made this one install I noticed a lot of of the php.ini configuration was off compared to my previous installs. Had issues with short php tags and so on. I think this one is along those lines, unfortunately I can't seem to find any information about this

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you have some postprocessing being done by Apache: I'd check that you don't have compression turned on in Apache.

I'd also try this: remove the last php tag at the end to make sure there is no output coming after the PNG data. And as previously pointed out, make sure there is absolutely NO whitespace before the first php tag.

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $PngImageBlob;
```